# Date format on input control

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm using *iReport 4.6.0* and *JasperReports Server 4.5.0*. I've created a report where I want to pass a date value to a *MySQL* database. I've created a parameter and used ***java.util.Date*** class. On the input control, I set it to a single value type, and the date data type. When running the report in *iReport* (using **Preview**), I'm prompted to select a date, and it generates the report using the specified date. After deploying the report to the *JasperReports Server*, when I'm prompted to enter a date, I get an empty report. I noticed the date format is different on the input control on the server (*`YYYY-MM-DD`*) than the one when previewing the report in *iReport* (*`MM/DD/YYYY`*). Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: The different formatting of the date doesn't mean there is a problem. Set the report to display "All sections, no data" when the query has no results. And display the parameter in the title band. Then you'll know for sure if the problem is with the date entered.

Comment: I added the parameter to the page and it returned null. Tom's solution fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with mdahlman. The formatting of the input control shouldn't be a problem. It should be passing a valid date value to the report.

Make sure that the name of the input control (not the label) exactly matches the name of your parameter. And it is case sensitive. If they are not identical, this could be your problem.

Comment: When I created the input control, I used all lower case letters. When I created the parameter, I used all upper case letters. Deleting the input control and creating a new one, with the ID in all upper case letters, fixed the issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help.  I've run into that issue more than once in the past.